# Determine reason for System.ObsoleteAttribute

Tags: .net

Is there a standard way to determine why a class is marked obsolete (other than a human typing things into google etc.)? If you stumble upon a warning about something being obsolete, there is an obvious next bit of information that is needed.

Comment: you mean class in c#?

Comment: I didn't see any mentions of WHY this particular class is obsolete, but main reason in most cases - there is a class, which do the same things better. And I often see messages like "This class is obsolete. Use %classname% instead". Good example is Lucene.net, where you can find lot of obsolete marked classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ObsoleteAttribute` has a [`Message`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.obsoleteattribute.message.aspx) property.

> Gets the workaround message, including a description of the alternative program elements.

When you use an obsolete type or member, this message appears in the compiler warning message. For example (`Message` highlighted in bold):

> 'System.IO.FileStream.FileStream(System.IntPtr, System.IO.FileAccess)' is obsolete: '"**This constructor has been deprecated.  Please use new FileStream(SafeFileHandle handle, FileAccess access) instead.  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=14202**"'

Unfotunately, I don't think .NET generally includes very descriptive messages, so if you need more information, especially as to *why*, it would probably be best to consult MSDN, or Google.

Answer (score 1):

> If you stumble upon a warning about something being obsolete, there is an obvious next bit of information that is needed.

Yup, and that's what the [`Message`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.obsoleteattribute.message.aspx) property is meant to convey.

See [this example](https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/source/browse/src/NodaTime/Period.cs#216) in Noda Time for example:

```
[Obsolete("Use FromMilliseconds instead. This method's name was a typo [...]")]
public static Period FromMillseconds(long milliseconds)
```

When making members obsolete, it's almost *always* a good idea to include a message telling people how they should avoid the obsolete member.

Comment: Thanks. And thanks to Kendall Frey. So, the answer is essentially, no there is not a standard way. A person has to hope that descriptive text was put in the attribute or search around.

Comment: @user1905156: No, on the contrary - the `Message` property *is* the standard way. In what way is it *not* a standard way? It's not like everyone writes their own subclass of `ObsoleteAttribute` and happens to use the same property name... this is the purpose of the `Message` property. Yes, it's just text - it's not some set of automatable refactoring instructions - but it's still a standard way of determining why it's changed and where to go instead.